# Sharepoint Workflow - Conditional auto approval

Tags: workflow

I have a standard OOTB approval workflow which I have associated with a list. I want auto approval of items in the list if the Rating field has been set to 1 or 2. Only ratings of 3 or higher need to go through the approval workflow.

How can I do this? In Sharepoint Designer I have edited a copy of the OOTB workflow to try and add the condition "If current item field equals value" But I cannot see the Rating field (or any fields) from the list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When editing a Sharepoint workflow in Designer you need to add the **Site Column** by clicking the **Association Columns** button.  After you add the Site Column you can reference it in the "**Current Item"** of the Workflow.