# How to auto approve a task?

Tags: workflow

I have a task assigned to a Approver in SP 2013 workflow. I want to auto approve the task after a certain period of inactivity using the workflow. I am setting the below fields on the task item

```
Set Task Outcome to Approved
Set Task Status to Completed
Set % Complete to 1
```

But the workflow is throwing the following error, when I check the outcome return value `if outcome equals Approved`

*Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)*

How can I auto approve a task?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since this way was throwing error, i used REST API to achieve the auto approve/reject the task. i followed the below links to get this done

[Updating list items using SharePoint 2013 workflow engine](http://blog.ch.atosconsulting.com/updating-list-items-using-sharepoint-2013-workflow-engine/)

[Approve workflow tasks using REST API in SharePoint 2013](https://spuser.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/approve-workflow-tasks-using-rest-api-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using a Second workflow (WF) on the task list, but the second WF does need to be a SP2010 WF not SP2013 WF.

Related Question: [How can you do task auto approval in SharePoint Designer workflow after their respective due date](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122040/how-can-you-do-task-auto-approval-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow-after-their-re/)